# Looking for suggestions on railing of split level home

Tags: railing

My house is a split level home with a 2.5' height difference between the family room and kitchen. The gap between the two walls is 11' wide. The current railing is metal with large gaps between bars.

Looking for suggestions for a glass railing that is toddler friendly. We are going to install new floating LVP so ideally the railing will primarily be supported by the walls with 1-2 floor mounts.

Do I need to worry about damage to the glass panels if the edges are hit? It seems like a lot of the options are frameless, however, I know glass panels can be shattered with a light hammer tap to the edges; is that true of railing glass?

Comment: Not sure what railing glass is made of, but I would at least check to make sure it is safety glass.  I imagine it is, like glass for showers.

Answer (score 1):

Glass used as a barrier in an interior must be tempered.
It's not likely that a toddler will break it, unless you let them play with a hammer.

Since you are not likely to be cutting glass and installing it ask your questions of the glass companies that you get proposals from.  They can advise you as to how and where it must be anchored as well as care and maintenance.